# Problems API Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

My API and json doesnt work after 7 days. I do not want to renew the json every 7 days. What is my fault? My projekt is to use an e-ink paper display to show all my events.

I use this: https://www.instructables.com/E-paper-Calendar-Raspberry-Pi-With-E-ink-Screen-an/

The problems are in these section:

Enable the API: this is easy
Credentials: Save the credentials.json file in the same folder as your main python file (the 'prog' folder) using NppFTP inside Notepad++ by rightclicking the folder and click 'Upload other file here' and selecte the credentials.json.
Install the Google python library: easy but don't forget to 'sudo reboot' afterwards
Copy the quickstart.py code inside a new document inside Notepad++ and save it to the 'prog' folder.
Important: Temporary delete the calendar.py file (or move it to another folder). Somehow you get an error when you run the quickstart.py if the calendar.py is in the same folder (see comments below).
Run quickstart.py once using VNC viewer (not from your PC!), because you need to login your Google account to create the 'token.json' file. Therefore launch the 'Terminal' in Raspberry Pi OS (see screenshot):
In the terminal type 'cd calendar/prog' and then 'python quickstart.py'
Chrome webbrowser will automatically open, to login your google account en give access to your project
A token.json file will automatically created inside the 'prog' folder
When done, your upcoming events will list inside the terminal!
Since the token.json file is created, you can now run the quickstart.py from your commandline on your PC. to get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Google Cloud Platform project's Publishing status set to `Testing` by any chance? Based on this [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration):

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen
> configured for an external user type and a publishing status of
> "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days

If it is indeed set to `Testing`, I suggest setting the Publishing status to `In production` instead.

### References:

- [Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)
- [Publishing status](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/cloud-project#choose_a_user_type_and_publishing_status)

Comment: Thanks for help! Yes it is set to Testing. But I do not want to set it to In production because other people should not see my calender events! What can I do (soory for the bad english I am an Austrian)

Comment: Hello Peter, I'm not aware of any other workarounds aside from setting your project's  Publishing status to `In production`. Howeve, I'd like to point out that other users should not see your calendar events even after changing the publishing status. The app will return the calendar data of the user who accesses it via OAuth. In other words, whenever another user accesses your app and logs in via OAuth, the project will return _their_ calendar data, not yours.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.  That make sense. I will try it :-)